# Derive individual land cover classes from .jpg map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, erdas-imagine, envi

I have a .jpg image which is land cover classification image with 9 classes. I want to extract raster image (.img file) which contains the same classes as .jpg image (9 classes too). Is there any tool to be used for this purpose in ARCGIS, ERDAS and ENVI?

Comment: I'm not a great expert on the subject but if you want to classify the image all three software has the tools to do it. First i guess you should change the color space to RGB and convert to .img or something similar. Then you have different methods of pixel and object classification which might produce different results. The quality mostly depends on how much time you are prepaired to invest. If the image has small extent it might be better to do it manually and with better quality as only RGB bands are usually not enough to perform very good classifications.

Comment: I have already done a classification which extracted from MODIS image. Here I meant that I want to use this jpg image as a ground truth map for accuracy assessment of my classification result because I don't have ground truth data on hand. So I'm searching the way to deal with accuracy assessment via this jpg img. To do this, I need an image contains information about individual classes. But the jpg image doesn't have such information, only a map with legend, showing 9 classes.

Comment: I mean that jpg image is a hardcopy map. I found a coordinate system is UTM from this map